# Visual Studio comparing workspaces

Tags: visual-studio, comparison, team-foundation-server, home-office

First, let me explain the situation:
I'm a software developer currently in home office.
Normally we're using a TFS to sync our sources, but from home I don't have a connection to the TFS.
So I'm getting source updates from my coworkers directly, which I then copy into my workspace.

Visual Studio still lists the pending changes I have in my workspace to the last version it saw online on the TFS.
That was resonably useful for some time.
But now I made a lot of changes and also got a lot of changes from my coworkers, so the list is getting way too big.

What other ways are there to let me see what i have actually worked on since the last source exchange with my coworkers?

What I could do, is make a workspace folder where I put the latest sources with all updates from my coworkers and then compare that whole folder to my current workspace.
But how can I do that?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to disconnect the project from the TFS repository.  Have you asked your IT staff for assistance in this matter?

Comment: We don't have IT staff, we're a very small company.

Comment: The problem is not the long list in general, I could just not view it, but i want the functionality of it in some form

Comment: So if I disconnect, it won't improve the situation, or will it?

Comment: If you disconnect the TFS repository from the project you would eliminate VS ability to track changes, but since you are tracking those manually, I suspect that isn't a deal breaker.  Without access to the current repository there really isn't a way to track the changes.